# Redis on Windows - Sentinels not communicating

Tags: windows, redis, sentinel

I am setting up my first Redis framework, and so far I have the following:

```
Server1: 
  - Redis master
  - 3 Redis Sentinels (quorum set to 2)
Server2:
  - Redis slave
  - 3 Redis Sentinels (quorum set to 2)
```

The master and slave appear to be working properly and data is syncing from the master to the slave.  When I install and start the sentinels, they too seem to run ok in the fact that if I connect to any of them, and run **sentinel masters**, it will show the sentinel is pointed at my Redis master and is showing the various properties.

However, the actual failover doesn't seem to work.  For example, if I connect to my Redis master and run **debug segfault** to get it to fail, the failover to the slave does not occur.  None of the sentinels log anything so it appears they are not actually connected.  Here is the configuration for my sentinels:

```
port 26381
sentinel monitor redismaster ServerName 26380 2
sentinel down-after-milliseconds redismaster 10000
sentinel failover-timeout redismaster 180000
sentinel parallel-syncs redismaster 1
logfile "nodes/sentinel1/sentinel.log"
```

As you can see, this sentinel runs on 26381 (and subsequent sentinels run on 26382 and 26383).  My Redis master runs on 26380.  All of the ports are open, names/IPs resolve correctly, etc., so I don't think it is an infrastructure issue.  In case it is useful, I am running Redis (2.8.17) which I downloaded from the MS Open Tech page.

Does anyone have any thoughts on what might be the problem, or suggestions on how to troubleshoot?  I am having a hard time finding accurate documentation for setting up a H.A. instance of Redis on Windows, so any commands useful for troubleshooting these types of issues would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out.  One thing I neglected to mention in my question is that I have the **masterauth** configuration specified in my Redis master config file, so my clients have to provide a password to connect.  I missed this in my sentinel configuration, and did not provide a password.  The sentinel logging does not indicate this, so it was not obvious to me.  Once I added this:

```
sentinel auth-pass redismaster <myPassword>
```

To my sentinel configuration file, everything started working as it should.